# Python: How to declare an object of class from another object which is also variable in this class?

Tags: python, class

```
class Apple:
    def print_my_tree_name(self):
        print('I want to use name of Tree on which I\'m hanging')


class Tree:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.apple = Apple()


a = Tree('test')
a.apple.print_my_tree_name()
```

Is it possible to access the `name` variable without passing self to the Apple class e.g. `a.apple.print_my_tree_name()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the name of the tree as an attribute of the apple in the tree constructor

```
class Apple:
    def print_my_tree_name(self):
        print('I am hanging on tree: %s'%self.tree_name)


class Tree:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.apple = Apple()
        self.apple.tree_name = name


a = Tree('test')
a.apple.print_my_tree_name()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this, using a `@staticmethod`

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.apple = Apple()

class Apple():

    @staticmethod
    def print_my_tree_name():
        print(f'Hanging on {a.name} tree.')

a = Tree('test')
a.apple.print_my_tree_name()
# Hanging on test tree.
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why you want to access `name` in Apple class but if I had to do this, I will implement it something as below

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Apple:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.tree = Tree(name)

    def print_my_tree_name(self):
        print('I want to use %s'%self.tree.name)


a = Tree('test')
a.print_my_tree_name()
```

See composition in python that is what you need basically. 
http://blog.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2014/08/20/python-3-oop-part-3-delegation-composition-and-inheritance/

Comment: Did you actually run this?

Comment: Hi, thx for suggestions, finally I would use variable to pass name of the tree to the apple object, I was wondering if there is standard way to access variables from - let me say creator, where it comes from. @viveksyngh - I would use name of the tree to get access to the right path on fs.